# Get message ID of last sent message from Discord.py webhook

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the sync code for my discord embed, I've been trying to get the message ID of the message sent so that I can edit it, I'm trying to automate some tasks but been unsuccessful so far.

Here's the code:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Post Title")
embed.add_field(name="Req AMount", value="100")
embed.add_field(name="Return AMount", value="120")

webhook = SyncWebhook.partial(1055498127618097174, "prxoD_ZW0vO6ghrwZNhOiwI9AeLBfNYYss6MTLPkjgvAb_B3WJgWNLMMtPWYZ67GTYbn")
sending = webhook.send(embed=embed)
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `webhook.send` message, if you set the parameter `wait` to **True**, you will get a `WebhookMessage` object returned, which you can then use the edit/delete the message your webhook sent.

Note that the `WebhookMessage` object doesn't have the ID parameter but has an `edit` and `delete` methods. Typically, as webhooks are used to send messages to channels/servers you might not have a bot in/permissions for, what you can do with the returned message object is a little less.

- [Webhook docs send here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook.send)
- [WebhookMessage docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.WebhookMessage)